# Why can I call max_element without "std::" and without "using namespace std"?

Tags: c++, stl, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider the following code:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
        std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
        max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
        return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine with gcc 7.2.0 and clang++ 3.9.1. I'd expect that I need to write `std::max_element`, but it seems that at least some functions in `<algorithm>` are in the global namespace - opposed to the draft of the C++17 standard, which shows the functions living in namespace std.

What is going on here?

Comment: `std` is deduced from the arguments, who's types belong to `std`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: you should post answers as answers, not comments.

Comment: Btw `std::vector<int>::iterator` might simply be `int*` and so ADL won't apply and `std::` would be required.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the explanation!